# Codeigniter select where function - undefined variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, select

I am trying to create a mailing list that sends to multiple users based on certain criteria within the database. I have successfully made a function that sends an email to everyone in my database, but I am trying to be more specific this time and email it to only members who are marked as paid. The paid field in the database is a varchar that can either be set as 'Y' or 'N'.

```
function get_paid_emails() {
    $this->db->select('email_address')->from('users')->where('paid', $y);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I keep getting undefined variable 'y' when I try to run it, but there are definitely members in the database that are set as paid - Y.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Is $y defined somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have selected the data where `paid` = `$y`, and didn't definied the $y variable. If you want to check if there are people with column `paid` like 'Y', you can do the following:

```
$this->db->select('email_address')->from('users')->where('paid', 'Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and read about scope in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

thats becouse u have not declered the variable y 
U can do this by chaning ur code to ..

```
function get_paid_emails() {
    $this->db->select('email_address')->from('users')->where('paid','Y');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function get_paid_emails($y) {
        $this->db->select('email_address')->from('users')->where('paid', $y);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

pass the value to this function as arguement or defined within this function or use direct values as below

`$this->db->select('email_address')->from('users')->where('paid', 'Y');` or

```
$this->db->select('email_address')->from('users')->where('paid', 'N');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its my bad I was using an online tutorial and misread it. I really meant to use 'Y' instead of $y, didn't need to use a variable at all.